# IOS - How do I add segments to NSURL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Suppose you have a URL that looks like `http://localhost:5867` and your wanted to append '/something' to the url. How do I append segments to this URL?
I am trying this:

```
//_baseURL is NSURL* and documentid is NSString*
NSURL* url = [_baseURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:documentid];
```

Oddly.. xcode(4.6.2) will not output the resulting URL to console.

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [url absoluteString]);//nothing output
```

Thanks!

**Edit**

I am working in a workspace. The code that I am debugging is a static lib which is in the workspace. Could this be the culprit of all this weirdness??

**Fixed**

I think the reason I was having problems was because my workspace was not configured correctly and I was actually executing an older version of my static lib. This explains why I wasn't getting NSLog'ing and why the result were unexpected. I found this [post](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/) which helped me understand the workspace and how to configure it for a static library. Thanks a lot for everyone's time!

Comment: What is the NSLog output of _baseURL ?

Comment: Nothing. It must be a bug. Ill restart XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class message,

```
+ (id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString relativeToURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

So,

```
NSURL *base  = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://localhost:5867"];
NSURL *child = [NSURL URLWithString: @"something" relativeToURL:base];
```

Comment: NSURL*url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"testdocument" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somewhere.com"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",url); //outputs http://somewhere.com

Comment: @nick That's extremely strange, it outputs the correct URL for me (ie `testdocument -- somewhere.com`). Can you reproduce the bug in a small test program?

Comment: I think the anomalies I was seeing had to do with my Workspace configuration. I believe I may have been executing an old version of the static lib and thus.. no logs and other random weirdness. I updated my question to include a blog which helped me figure out my configuration. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *base  = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:5867"];
NSURL *url = [base URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"something"];

NSLog(@"%@", [url absoluteString]);
```

This works for me and prints `http://localhost:5867/something`, so check your variables (maybe one of them is `nil` or an empty string?).